# Use power supply from Coral SOM or obtain from DCDC Converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, pmic

I'm designing a carrier board for Coral SOM.

[image]

[image]

DCDC_3V3 and VDDA_1V8 are SOM outputs, according with Google, they are using PMIC BD71837MWV to get this outputs, but they are not using them in their carrier board, using other DCDC dual channel converter. What is the difference between using PMIC Outputs and DCDC Converter outputs?

Comment: I don't understand negative vote and close vote, why? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The downvote faeries usually don't provide feedback on where you can improve. Looking at the timeline, at least it seems that the close vote got denied.